# What is the best way to implement a vertical flowed text in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I'm having a changeable text like in the screenshot, where the quantity changes according to plus and minus buttons.

What is the best to implement that on Android ?

Could I make use of Spannable text in this case ? Or do I implement that with 
a vertical LinearLayout with a TextView then a separator view then another TextView that changes ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to achieve this layout, using LinearLayout.

It was straightforward I thought that it might need tricky layout technique, but turned out to be easy.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/quantity"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="01"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it your own way, look for `click` events on the plus and minus buttons, change an integer variable (say `mQuantity`) according to these click event (`mQuantity++` or `mQuantity--` respectively), and change the `TextView` content with `mQuantityLabel.setText(mQuantity+"");`. That extra `+""` is to avoid `setText` looking for a probably non existing `id` inside `strings.xml`. You could just need to convert the int to String, but this suffices for this case.

However, and it may be more sensible to go for already established solutions for number increase/decrease such as [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) (after API 11) or [SimonVT's NumberPicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) (backport of NumberPicker, if the minSdkVersion is prior to API 11).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I was not asking about the logic, it is straight forward. What I was asking is how this layout going to be implemented in Android.

Comment: use a numberpicker, and you can skip thinking about it, actually